# Java - Android - view.getContext() meaning

Tags: java, android

Hello i have just started learning android application development and i am watching a lot of tutorials but none of them really describe step by step so my question is :

i have created a simple app which contains on `TextView` one `EditText` and one `Button`

i have added `android:onClick="onButtonClick"` to my `Button` so it will trigger the `onButtonClick` method , now , i would like it to print out the userinput from `EditText` so what i did is :

```
 public void onButtonClick(View v){
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), email.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

but why the method has to contain the `View v` ? where is it passed from ? and what does it contain ? it contains the button which i clicked  ? and what does the `v.getContext()` do?  why my app does the same when replacing the `v.getContext()` with `this` ?

Answer (score 1):

That are many questions at once, but I try to answer them one by one.

> but why the method has to contain the View v ? where is it passed from ? and what does it contain ?

Consider the [documentation of View.OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html#onClick(android.view.View)):

> View: The view that was clicked.

So you are correct in your assumption that it is the View that has been clicked.

> and what does the v.getContext() do?

The first parameter of the `Toast#makeText` method is a `Context`. Basically the `Context` is a container of global information in an Android application. The `Toast` needs it to retrieve information to show itself.

> why my app does the same when replacing the v.getContext() with this ?

I assume your method resides in an `Activity`. An [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is a subclass of `Context` and can be used as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you click a button then View is passed. ViewGroup is a group of View example LinearLayout, Relative Layout, FrameLayout,etc. View is a part of ViewGroup. According to [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), A View occupies a rectangular area on the screen and is responsible for drawing and event handling. View is the base class for widgets, which are used to create interactive UI components (buttons, text fields, etc.). The ViewGroup subclass is the base class for layouts, which are invisible containers that hold other Views (or other ViewGroups) and define their layout properties.
I hope you understand well about what is View and ViewGroup!!